# DataGridCell showing blank spaces at top and bottom in WPF after applying padding to DataGridCell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcell

I have below Style defined for DataGridCell:

```
<Style x:Key="MyDataGridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/> <!-- Padding cell -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridCell}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And then I apply it to my datagrid, but there are three columns (below shown) that are not displayed well, I mean, some blank space is left at top and bottom of the cell content.

```
<dg:DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" SelectionMode="Single" 
             AlternationCount="2" AlternatingRowBackground="Bisque"
             Focusable="False" SelectionUnit="FullRow"
             CellStyle="{StaticResource MyDataGridCellStyle}">

   <dg:DataGrid.Columns>

       <!-- THERE ARE MORE COLUMNS. I ONLY SHOW HERE THE ONES THAT ARE DISPLAYED BAD -->
       <dg:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Col2" 
                              Header="Col2Name" 
                              MinWidth="65" Width="auto"
                              IsReadOnly="True"                                               
                              Binding="{Binding Path=Col2Value}" />

       <dg:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Col3" 
                              Header="Col3Name" 
                              MinWidth="55" Width="auto"
                              IsReadOnly="True"
                              Binding="{Binding Path=Col3Value}" />

       <dg:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Col5"
                              Header="Date"
                              MinWidth="75" Width="auto"
                              IsReadOnly="True"
                              Binding="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat='{}{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}'}">

   </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
</dg:DataGrid>
```

Below the screenshot with the problem:

[image] I pixeled the information for confidentiality.

Comment: I'd guess that the images are taller than the text, and each item is only taking the space it needs.

Comment: Yep. I also think your problem is somewhere in the columns you're not showing us the xaml for. If you comment out all but those three columns you show us then the rows are narrower and no problem - no gaps?  You could also try just removing that border verticalalignment and let it fill it's container.